# Counter loop and average

Tags: java, arrays

I want to enter marks of 5 subjects in an `array` and calculate their average and run the counter loop **5** times and then display the `name` and `average`.

```
package enstudentrunner;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class EnStudent {
    private String Name;
    public int[] Result_array=new int[5];
    public EnStudent(String Name,int Result_array[])
    {   this.Name=Name;
        for(int count=0;count<Result_array.length;count++)
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter marks");
            Result_array[count]=input.nextInt();
        }
    }
    public int Average()
    {
        int total=0;
        for(int counter=0;counter<Result_array.length;counter++)
        {
            total+=Result_array[counter];
        }
        return total/5;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("your name is"+this.Name+"average is"+Average());
    }

}
package enstudentrunner;

public class EnStudentRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
         int[] Result_array=new int[5];

        EnStudent Std = new EnStudent("Usama",Result_array);
        Std.Average();
        Std.display();
        }
    }
```

I expect the output of `{50,60,70,80,90}` to be `70` but the actual output is `0`

Comment: Learning how to debug your own code is a critical skill that you need to develop as a beginner. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips to get you started.

Comment: Besides learning to use a debugger, you're hiding the `Result_array` in the first two methods.  Then when `Average()` runs the instance variable `Result_array` isn't initialized and all zero.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `Result_array` from your main and updating that array instead of using `this.Result_array`. There is no point in passing the `Result_array`.

Answer (score 0):

So, some tips about coding convention first. In java and most languages, please start you variable with a lower case letter. It increases readability.

So the problem you are having is scoping of variables. 
In you constructor

```
    public EnStudent(String Name,int Result_array[])
```

you referenced `Result_array`. The way java scoping works is that it always reference the variable with the smallest scope. So in this case, the local variable (argument) `Result_array` is used. Thus the values are stored in the array you passed in. The problem comes when you compute the average, you are referencing the array you created inside the `EnStudent` class. (Member variable) Which is never assigned to, it is all empty.

There are two options to fix this:

1) You could remove the parameter `Result_array` in your construction. It seems redundant.

2) You could assign this argument to the member variable `Result_array`. (And if you do this, the member variable does not need to be initialized.)

Hope you find this helpful.